# Node MySql case sensitive

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

Hola tengo una duda estoy migrando una api desde php a Node, sin embargo un ejemplo seria en Php yo hago una búsqueda de un correo y este me muestra el resultado sin importar si la búsqueda está en mayúscula o minúscula, en node no, todo debe coincidir, me fui a la consola de mysql y este tampoco tiene restricción sensitiva, por tanto hay algo que hace la librería mysql de Node que genera esa particularidad, alguien sabe como desactivarla?

Agrego detalles:

En php:

```
Select * from usuarios where usuario = 'alguien@correo.com'

Retorna:

user|correo
otro|Alguien@correo.com
oxyz|AlGUien@correo.com
```

En consola MySql:

```
Select * from usuarios where usuario = 'alguien@correo.com'

Returna:

user|correo
otro|Alguien@correo.com
oxyz|AlGUien@correo.com
```

En node:

```
Select * from usuarios where usuario = 'alguien@correo.com'
No trae resultados
```

codigo en node usando mysql kenex y objection Sin resultado

```
await Usuarios.query()
.select('id','level')
.where({usuario:'alguien@correo.com'})
.then(result => {
console.log(result)
});
```

codigo en node usando solo mysql Sin resultado

```
await pool.query('select * from usuarios where usuario = \'alguien@correo.com\'', (error, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        if(result!=''){
         console.log(result)
        }
```

codigo en node usando mysql kenex y objection Con resultado

```
await Usuarios.query()
.select('id','level')
.where({usuario:'Alguien@correo.com'})
.then(result => {
console.log(result)
});
```

codigo en node usando solo mysql Con resultado

```
await pool.query('select * from usuarios where usuario = \'Alguien@correo.com\'', (error, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        if(result!=''){
         console.log(result)
        }
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia, y sin ver lo que estás haciendo es complicado darte una respuesta. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Ya actualice la pregunta con ejemplos, en realidad es una pregunta bastante generica para una peculiaridad. El caso se me da sobre todo cuando un usuario intenta loguearse desde un movil, que automaticamente al hacer focus en el campo nombre de usuario la primera letra queda en mayuscula, por tanto al realizar la consulta sql no puede loguearse, a menos que yo en el JS convierta la cadena a minuscula, la pregunta deriva porque si la misma consola de Mysql no me hace esta distincion, porque node si.

Comment: *En node*, eso no es código Javascript, es simplemente una consulta SQL, necesitas especificar cómo realizas dicha consulta, indicando la librería o módulo usado para la misma. Coloca el código actual de tu implementación en Node, es la forma de realizar correctamente la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Ya puse el codigo, aunque no se si tenga mucho que ver, si tienes experiencia, favor ayudame con eso

Comment: En PHP (y en la consola de MySQL) la consulta la haces a la tabla `usuarios` discriminando por el campo `correo`, pero en NodeJS, haces la consulta a la tabla `usuarios` pero discriminando por el campo `usuario`. ¿Podrías aclarar esa discrepancia en las consultas?

Comment: Listo, hago la consulta contra la misma tabla y el mismo campo, pasa que en los primeros ejemplos lo saque de mi imaginacion para hacer un ejemplo, pero ya lo modifique

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer uso de ILIKE para comparacion sin case sensitive.

Usando knex seria algo asi.

```
*.where('columnName', 'like', '%rowlikeme%')
```

Usando el driver de mysql seria algo asi.

```
'select * from usuarios where usuario ILIKE \'Alguien@correo.com\''
```